# How to Make Image Responsive with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS properties `max-width` and `height` to make images responsive but it is not working for me in some cases.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}
```

**Question**: **Is there any other CSS approach to make an image responsive?**

Comment: Since you removed the link example, you should provide more code; otherwise the scope of your question is completely unclear.  But even when you had the link example, I was going to mention, it was unclear which images specifically you were having trouble with.  Overall, when I looked at your site yesterday though, I wanted to mention.. the overall structure of your page is very poor.. you may want to consider restructuring your code and in doing so you'll likely have far fewer difficulties such as this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am having trouble with the main image on homepage as well as the background on post pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you target the element you are trying to adjust more specifically that will help.  For example, on the Einstein image you have a class

```
.entrybody img
```

which is more specific than

```
img {}
```

Also, percentage based dimensions only work if the parents dimension is set.

Comment: What if the parents dimension is set as 100vw width?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `width` properties instead of `max-width`

```
img {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}
```